# C# WebSocket with Proxy

Tags: c#, websocket, pusher

I'm using Pusher in my WCF application with [pusher-websocket-dotnet](https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-dotnet).
This is working fine!

But when the server machine is under proxy, not connect.

The .net WebSocket class has an property Proxy derived from `SuperSocket.ClientEngine.IproxyConnector` and I would like to know how to configure the proxy in it, because it is not a type WebProxy object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxy support isn't yet in this community library. See:
https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-dotnet/issues/11

A pull request would be gratefully received.